# Converting 2D Map to Flat map like in Google

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, style, software-recommendations, 3d

My requirement is shown below by maps.

**Map 1--My Map**
[image: Map 1--My Map]

**Map 2--I required**
[image: Map 2--I required]

[image: Map 2--I required]

I am using GeoServer v2.2 (for publishing the map) and OpenLayers v2.11 (to display the map). According to my client requirement I published one layer with name "**3d Buildings**" in GeoServer and given a 3D style.

I added this layer as WMS in OpenLayers.

Now its look like a 2.5D Map(refer "Map 1").

My Questions are;

**In Geoserver**

1. Look at the buildings in "Map 1" its showing flat roofs, But I need different shapes of roofs like the buildings in "Map 2".
2. Or How can I load 3D models to a layer?

**In Openlayers(2.11)**

3. How can I rorate/flat map like google earth? Please see the "Map 2" which is in flat view. you can see sky also .In Google API they are using "**map.setTilt(45)**" to change the map angle. Like this any option is available in openlayers?.
4. Or How can give Navigation Controls like in google earth?
5. How Can I load 3D Models on map?

**If these features are not available in GeoServer and OpenLayers, can you introduce me to a new tool?**

Comment: There are too many questions here, please focus on one at a time.

Comment: Please see [**What makes a good question?**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question) for advice on how to focus your question.

Comment: I am sorry blah238, PolyGeo thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Out Cesium which is a JavaScript library for creating 3D globes and 2D maps in a web browser without a plugin. visit http://cesium.agi.com/index.html to download and try

Comment: Farhat Thanks a lot, I downloaded "Cesium" It  is really amazing!!. I added my map to the globe, Now I am able to drag, tilt, rotate. Just one more help... Can you please explain me-How to add KML files Which are created through "Google Sketch up(tool to create 3D Models)" on the map.

Comment: you should use an open-source KML to CZML converter in the czml-writer [https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer] project.  You can convert KML files to CZML, and then drag and drop them into Cesium Viewer.  I don't know all of the details off-hand, but cesium support major features like placemarks, polylines, polygons, and text.  cesium do not support 3D models yet. :)